# image positioning after load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with positioning images (centering into div container) after they are loaded. Javascript code which I use works on PHP, but there is a problem, probably because I use Url.Action. Some images moves, and some stay.

```
              foreach(GetFriendsItem hItem in (List<GetFriendsItem>)Model)
              {
                  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Users/_UserProfile.cshtml", hItem );
              }
```

/Views/Users/_UserProfile.cshtml

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Show", "Image", new { id = @Model.m_unUserID })" class="imageNarrowly image" />
```

javascript

```
 $(function() {

    $(".image").load(function(index, val){
      // dimensions of the image
      var imageWidth = $(this).width();
      var imageHeight = $(this).height();

      var parentHeight = $(this).parents($(this).parent).height();
      var parentWidth = $(this).parents($(this).parent).width();


      if (parentHeight > imageHeight){
        topOffset = (parentHeight/2 - imageHeight/2);
        $(this).css({'top': topOffset}); 
      }

      if (parentWidth > imageWidth){
        leftOffset = (parentWidth/2 - imageWidth/2);
        $(this).css({'left': leftOffset}); 
      }
    });


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position` property along with `left` or `top`

```
$(".image").load(function(index, val){
  // dimensions of the image
  var imageWidth = $(this).width();
  var imageHeight = $(this).height();

  var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
  var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();


  if (parentHeight > imageHeight){
    topOffset = (parentHeight/2 - imageHeight/2);
    $(this).css({'top': topOffset,'position':'relative'}); 
  }

  if (parentWidth > imageWidth){
    leftOffset = (parentWidth/2 - imageWidth/2);
    $(this).css({'left': leftOffset,'position':'relative'}); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Same thing, there is no changes.

Comment: Check the `parent height, width` and `image height,width`, or simply `alert` all these. Also you can check the `positions` in `console`.